# Is there a way to remove or edit Blockchain.info public notes?

Tags: blockchain.info, transaction-messaging, public-note

I want to use blockchain.info's public note feature to build an app, but I was wondering can you delete or edit an existing public note you made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ask this question to blockchain.info support. Nobody here can predict the near and far future. Nobody here is responsible for third-party service like blockchain.info